# AuthToken.getAccessToken()'s return value is NULL

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, auth

Implementing SSO with Okta and need to access to retrieve Okta's userinfo with access token.Tried the following code to retrieve access token in Auth.RegistrationHandler's createUser method but the return value is NULL.

```
String accessToken = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken('0SO5w000000bxAi' ,'open id connect');
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried the 18-character ID, as suggested by the doc? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthToken.htm

Comment: Provider name is 'Open ID Connect', might be case-sensitive. You shouldn't need to hit Okta. `Auth.UserData` should have everything you need, it's based on info Okta sends. And if you need more attributes/claims, you can get Okta to send more.

Comment: @TheSFDCTower Ofcourse,  I tried with 18 sfdc ID but the return value is NULL.

Comment: @identigral I tried with 'Open ID Connect', but the return value is NULL. I need more Okta user info to insert on user object. That's why, I need to use access token to callout to Okta user info url.Auth.UserData doesn't contain what all I need user info.

Comment: >And if you need more attributes/claims, you can get Okta to send more. 
@identigral OK, I see. I will try it. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer from here: Stackoverflow ([Custom REST controller to access Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken returning null](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321814/custom-rest-controller-to-access-auth-authtoken-getaccesstoken-returning-null))

Simple Answer is: Open Authentication Provider, open on the OAuth-Only Initialization URL, login. Now you get the Accesstoken!